# How can you use the actual regex value in an environment variable?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm writing a shell script for an assignment. The script is supposed to read regex argument and then use that regex. The problem is, if the user doesn't use single/double quotations then the regex will be evaluated before I need it to be evaluated.

Here's an example; let's say that the user executed the script and passed *f* as an argument, and the code has the following lines:

```
arg=$1 #*f*

echo "$arg"
```

In the above example echo returns a file name in the current directory that contains the regex *f*. I need echo to print *f*. It works if the user passes '*f*', but is there no other way?

Comment: You tried `arg="$1"`? If user didn't quote the argument there is nothing you can do

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah, I tried that but it didn't help. I was wondering if there's a way to read the actual content of the argument without evaluating it.

Comment: Nah, afaik there is no way. Like, if you run `prog *`, shell  will try to expand `*` and if it manages, there is no reliable way of getting `*` from within `prog`. But you can always blame users for being ignorant :D

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks, buddy!

Comment: `*f*` is not a regex. It's a shell pattern, commonly known as a "glob". Make sure your assignment is actually about globs and not regexes.

Comment: @rici I've never heard of globs before. I'll look it up! Thanks!